# Connect to IBM DB2 from Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo, db2, odbc

I have never worked with DB2 before. I am trying to connect from codeigniter. I have used the following settings in my database config file:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'ipAddress';
$db['default']['port'] = 'portNumber';
$db['default']['username'] = 'uname';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'myDBName';
//$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and it throws the following error:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\archive\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

Again, I am totally new to DB2, so in case I need to install anything extra (I assume the driver is already included in my latest CI download) or I need to define a dsn (please let me know how to do that if i require that) please do let me know, will very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Any errors on the DB server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to install the IBM Data Server Client package, or at least Runtime Client. Download the appropriate driver from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878

The manual explains how to [configure DB2 access from a PHP application](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/c0021523.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will go through those links and get back, hope that works.

Comment: keep getting this error "the program cant start because php5.dll is missing from your computer", googled that and tried different php_.dll files as suggested, but no luck.

Comment: Helping someone with this issue.. For those who use DB2 or dashDB with CodeIgniter, wanted to add this link in addition to items above:
http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-1608.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the full connection to the hostname parameter , as the following code

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = FALSE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = "driver={IBM db2 odbc DRIVER};Database=DBNAME;hostname=localhost;port=50000;protocol=TCPIP;" . "uid=username; pwd=password";
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'DBNAME.SCHEMANAME';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```